# ¿Cómo filtrar un campo en una ListView de Django con un If?

Tags: python, django

Tengo un modelo que se llama Inventory y quiero filtrar la columna de quantityInventory para que sólo aparezca en stock que tiene menos de 10. Así como lo tengo me aparecen todos los datos, hasta los de 50 y el punto en ese template es que sólo aparezca  lo que hay en poca cantidad, no todos los datos.

**En resumen**: Usar un if condicional  para decir que si quantityInventory < 10 se filtre y en el template sólo muestre el número de los quantityInventory que son menores que 10

¿Me pueden ayudar? Gracias

> views.py

```
class pendingStock(ListView):
   model=Inventory
   template_name = 'ReporteGanancias/reports-pending-stock.html'
   context_object_name='inventory'
   queryset=Inventory.objects.all()
```

> models.py

```
class Inventory(models.Model):
   STATUS = (
       ('Ok', 'Ok'),
       ('Pending', 'Pending'),
   )
   dealer = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
   codigoInventory=models.CharField(max_length=255,blank=True)
   invoiceNumber=models.IntegerField()
   descriptionInventory= models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
   quantityInventory=models.IntegerField(default=0)
   unitPriceInventory=models.IntegerField()
   minimumInventory=models.IntegerField()

 
   status=models.CharField(max_length=255,choices=STATUS,default='Ok')
   fecha_registro = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)



   def __str__(self):
       return f'{self.dealer}: {self.codigoInventory} {self.invoiceNumber} {self.descriptionInventory} ' \
              f'{self.quantityInventory} {self.unitPriceInventory}{self.minimumInventory}{self.status}{self.fecha_registro}'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo de esta manera:

```
class pendingStock(ListView):
   model=Inventory
   template_name = 'ReporteGanancias/reports-pending-stock.html'
   context_object_name='inventory'
   queryset=Inventory.objects.filter(quantityInventory__lt=10)
```

Lo que hace con el __lt al final es indicarle que filtre por quantityInventory menor a 10. Si quisieras que fuera menor o igual seria con __lte

Puedes ver mas filtros disponibles aqui: https://pythonguides.com/python-django-filter/